# Show data in ng-repeat from Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have data that cames from firebase in JSON format like this:

```
"events" : [{
"event_score" : [0,1],
"user_scores": {"simplelogin:1" : {"user_score":[0,0]}}, {"simplelogin:2" : {"user_score":[3,0]}}, ...
},
{
"event_score" : [0,1],
"user_scores": {"simplelogin:1" : {"user_score":[0,0]}}, {"simplelogin:2" : {"user_score":[3,0]}}, ...
},
...
]
```

simplelogin:1 is the same as currentUser.$id below in the controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyApp.controllers').controller('DashboardCtrl', 
  function($scope, $timeout, $firebase, FIREBASE_ROOT, Auth) {
      //get events list from firebase 
      var eventsRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_ROOT + '/events');
      var usersRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_ROOT + '/users');
      var currentUserRef = usersRef.child(Auth.currentUser.uid);
      var currentUser = $firebase(currentUserRef);

      $scope.screen_name = currentUser.$id;
      $scope.eventsRef = eventsRef;

      eventsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        $timeout(function() {
          var snapshotVal = snapshot.val();
          $scope.events = snapshotVal;
        });
      });
  });
```

and I'm try to show it on the page like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="e in events">
<p>{{e.match_score}}</p>
<p>{{e.match_userScore.screen_name.user_score}}</p>
</div>
```

{{e.match_userScore.screen_name.user_score}} don't work. But I don't know is it possible to inject variable from the scope to object path inside {{}}? Or there is another way?

Comment: Why the weird almagamation of Firebase SDK and AngularFire? Is something wrong with `$scope.events = $firebase(eventsRef).$asArray()`? It seems shorter and faster than all of this. There is [also an entire guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html) dedicated to this fundamentals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't know is it possible to inject variable from the scope to object path inside {{}}?

Yes, it's possible. Since you provide a javascript-like expression between `{{` and `}}` which is parsed by Angular, you can access values by property name stored in variable using bracket notation:

```
{{e[match_userScore][screen_name].user_score}}
```